# Uncaught Error: <Navigate> may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation-v6

It says "in the context of `<Router/>`", in my case `BrowserRouter`. The `Home`-component is in `Route` < `Routes` < `BrowserRouter`. So it is in the context of a router no? It's definitely not outside of the `Router` which was the problem for other posts.

Index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="myEdu" element={<MyEdu />} />
            <Route path="completed" element={<Completed />} />
            <Route path="myEmployees" element={<MyEmployees />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Home/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js:

```
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home() {
    return(
        !localStorage.getItem("userId")
        ?
        <Navigate to="/login"/>
        :
        <h1>this is the home page...</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a route with `<Home />` as component but right after the closing tag `<BrowserRouter />` you have a second `<Home />` component. Removing the latter should resolve the issue.

Comment: Damn...I was SO blinded by the Home.js >:(  Thanks!